# please help onjquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs. Say div1 and div2. By default div2 is invisible.

When the user hovers over div1, I need to display div2. Now if the div2 is hovered then i need to keep displaying this div2 (even if div1 is no longer hovered), otherwise reset the div2's visibility to hidden.

How do I keep div2 visible while hovered?

Comment: Sibling divs or nested divs? `<div></div><div></div>` or `<div><div></div></div>`?

Comment: sibling..........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var overSubmenuFlag = false;
$('#div1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#div2').show();
});
$('#div1').mouseout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){if(overSubmenuFlag)return;$('#div2').hide();},100);
});
$('#div2').mouseover(function(){
    overSubmenuFlag = true;
});
$('#div2').mouseout(function(){
    overSubmenuFlag = false;
    $('#div2').hide();
});
```

Comment: will not work.. div1 is the menu.. and div2 is submenu.. if div1 is hover then div2 is shown.. but if div2 is not on hover, i need to hide div2

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `hover` for both divs.

When hovering over `div1` show `div2`, when hovering out of `div2` hide `div2`.

```
$('#div1').hover(
function() {
 //hoverIn
 $('#div2').show(); 
}, function() {
  //hoverOut
});


$('#div2').hover(
function() {
 //hoverIn

}, function() {
  //hoverOut
  $('#div2').hide();
});
```

Comment: will not work.. div1 is the menu.. and div2 is submenu.. if div1 is hover then div2 is shown.. but if div2 is not on hover, i need to hide div2

Comment: Well you didn't say that in your question ... :)